# PHP/MySQL query not working with no error

Tags: php, mysql

I have written that seems to not be working, but MySQL does not return any error. It is supposed to get data from `database1.table` to update `database2.table.column`

```
<?php
    $dbh1 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'tendesig_zink', 'password') or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $dbh2 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'tendesig_zink', 'password', true) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    mysql_select_db('tendesig_zink_dev', $dbh1);
    mysql_select_db('tendesig_zink_production', $dbh2);

    $query = " UPDATE 
                    tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product, 
                    tendeig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product 
                SET 
                    tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity = tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity
                WHERE 
                    tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id = tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id";
    if (mysql_query($query, $dbh1 ))
    {
    echo "Record inserted";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error inserting record: " . mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: "No error" means that you get "Record inserted"?

Comment: great thanks for the coding tips i will try to make adjustments.

Comment: This should be producing tons of errors because it isn't possible to bridge between two MySQL databases with PHP and then run a single query that manipulates both databases.

Comment: I get "Error inserting record: *blank* @ÁlvaroG.Vicario

Comment: I wonder who down-voted this question and why.. It's a perfectly reasonable question in my opinion. It's about programming. It shows effort and it contains only the relevant code. Sure, there are problems with the implementation but that's why it is a question here..

Comment: @tadman: It's perfectly possible to run a single query with PHP, even with old mysql_query that selects from a table in one database and inserts or updates another table in a second database. What's needed: a user with the same name and the same password for both databases and enough rights.

Comment: @VMai If they're on the same server, but this may not be the case if you have two independently configured connections.

Comment: @tadman...this thread has gotten a little confusing for me, but to answer your question...they are on the same server. two separate databases using the same database user/pwd. basically one is a development version the other is the production. I guess at this poiont I just need to know the how.

Answer (score 3):

The [manual page for `mysql_error()`](http://php.net/mysql_error) mentions this about the optional parameter you're omitting:

> `link_identifier`
>   The MySQL connection. **If the link identifier is not
>   specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed.** If no
>   such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect()
>   was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or
>   established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

So it's reading errors from `$dbh2`, which is the last connection you've opened. However, you never run any query on `$dbh2`:

```
mysql_query($query, $dbh1 )
```

Thus you get no errors because you are reading errors from the wrong connection.

The solution is to be explicit:

```
mysql_error($dbh1)
```

As about what you're trying to accomplish, while you can open as many connections as you want, those connections won't merge as you seem to expect: they're independent sessions to all effects.

All your tables are on the same server and you connect with the same users, there's absolutely no need to even use two connections anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just issue a cross-database update statement from PHP like that!

You will need to execute a query to read data from the source db (execute that on the source database connection: `$dbh2` in your example) and then separately write and execute a query to insert/update the target database (execute the insert/update query on the target database connection: `$dbh1` in your example).

Essentially, you'll end up with a loop that reads data from the source, and executes the update query on each iteration, for each value you're reading from the source.

Comment: so if i am grasping this, i need to query db2 and do a SELECT query, then in a foreach loop i will do my query UPDATE to db1?

Comment: yeah, that's the general idea

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyone's help/banter, here is what finally worked for me.

```
<?php
    $dba = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'tendesig_zink', 'pswd', 'tendesig_zink_production') or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $query = "  UPDATE 
                tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product, tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product
                SET 
                tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity = tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity
                WHERE 
                tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id = tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id";
    if (mysqli_query($dba, $query))
    {
    echo "Records inserted";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error inserting records: " . mysqli_error($dba);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hopefully that password that you included with your post is not the password that you're actually using (there or anywhere else)..